# Зачем мы создаем интерфейс-репозиторий в Spring проэктах?

Tags: java, spring, интерфейс

Зачем мы всегда создаем интерфейс-репозитории, которые ничего не делают, кроме как наследуются от JPARepository? К чему эта лишняя прослойка, если в сервисе мы с таким же успехом могли бы просто обращаться напрямую к JPARepository?
Вообще впринципе с интерфейсами у меня туго, сколько учу джаву, а для чего они нужны так и не понял.. Может кто посоветует источник, который доходчиво обьяснил бы мне, тугодуму. =(
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: JpaRepository имеет общие методы для всех сущностей. В 99.9% случаев есть необходимость писать свои, отличные от стандартных, запросы к бд конкретной сущности - поиск по какому-то полю или полям и т.д..

Суть Spring Data JPA в том, что реализация интерфейсов генерируется при запуске. А нам остаётся использовать интерфейс. Бывают случаи, когда мы можем написать реализацию - это не запрещено.

Answer (score 4):

JpaRepository – это интерфейс фреймворка Spring Data предоставляющий набор стандартных методов JPA для работы с БД.

А создаем мы интерфейс для реализации шаблона проектирования DAO, который впринципе является базой в написании фреймворков на Spring, некоторые так же предпочитают слой Repository не DAO, а именно Repository, просто для того что бы структура проекта была более читабельна

Про DAO я рекомендую почитать вот тут, довольно подробное и понятное обьяснение: https://www.baeldung.com/java-dao-pattern

Answer (score 1):

Программирование на уровне interface делает программу более гибкой, так как класс может наследовать сколько угодно interface, так образом мы можем более гибко модифицировать класс и как следствие(объект). Если мы используем абстрактный класс, то класс, который его наследует может принимать только - 1 класс. Создается проблема пирамиды.